# Oracle report layout issue

Tags: sql, oracle, reportbuilder

I'm using report builder and my DML is fetching my result set to show on report builder but my client wants it to show up in a grid layout. What kind of trigger or formula can manipulate where the answer will fall on the layout based on the value of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use formula column. And use a case statement to return the answer based on the value of the answer.
Suppose you answer has integer value and answer return string.